# How to pass 2 conditions to where clause in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I would like to pass two `where` conditions to the `where clause` in `sqlalchemy`. However, it threw different kinds of `error`. When I use ',' in `return self._get_jobs`, it warned me it only accepts 2 parameter. I also tried to turn them into string, but not work. Belows are my code and trial. How can I solve it? Cheers

Code:

```
def get_due_jobs(self, now):
    timestamp = datetime_to_utc_timestamp(now)
    return self._get_jobs(self.next_run_time <= timestamp and self.jobs_t.c.name = self.name)

def _get_jobs(self, *conditions):
    jobs = []
    selectable = select([self.jobs_t.c.id, self.jobs_t.c.job_state]).\
        order_by(self.jobs_t.c.next_run_time)
    selectable = selectable.where(*conditions) if conditions else selectable
    failed_job_ids = set()
    for row in self.engine.execute(selectable):
        try:
            jobs.append(self._reconstitute_job(row.job_state))
        except BaseException:
            self._logger.exception('Unable to restore job "%s" -- removing it', row.id)
            failed_job_ids.add(row.id)

# Remove all the jobs we failed to restore
if failed_job_ids:
    delete = self.jobs_t.delete().where(self.jobs_t.c.id.in_(failed_job_ids))
    self.engine.execute(delete)

return jobs
```

What I tried is turn them to string:

```
def get_due_jobs(self, now):
    timestamp = datetime_to_utc_timestamp(now)
    return self._get_jobs(f"{self.next_run_time} <= {timestamp} and {self.jobs_t.c.name} = {self.name}")

def _get_jobs(self, *conditions):
    jobs = []
    selectable = select([self.jobs_t.c.id, self.jobs_t.c.job_state]).\
        order_by(self.jobs_t.c.next_run_time)
    selectable = selectable.where(text(*conditions)) if conditions else selectable
```

Comment: On what line is it failing? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @Ben Hi, this line is failing  "selectable = selectable.where(*conditions) if conditions else selectable" . The error is Textual SQL expression error

Comment: How do you create what gets sent to conditions? Is it a set of manually written SQL statements or statements that SQLAlchemy generates?

Comment: @Ben it is part of code from apscheduler actually. The conditions is manually written by me. Initially, it only has one condition "self.next_run_time <= {timestamp". But now I would like to add one more on it.

Comment: I'm not positive but I wonder if the manually created SQL is screwing you up. Is it possible to have SQLAlchemy generate those? If not, can you test but having it create a couple of dummy, generated SQL statements and see if that crashes?